# Automator - find and move most recent file in filtered list

Tags: bash, automator

I'm trying to use Automator to

1. get a filtered list of files in a folder that are more than 30 days old (ok)
2. move the most recent of those (if there are any) to an existing subfolder
3. trash the others.

Step 1 is easy enough, but I haven't been able to find a way to do step 2 -- select and move the most recent of the filtered set.

The outcome would be: if the workflow is scheduled once a month, then the subfolder will contain one file per month, & the parent folder will contain only files less than 31 days old

Is there a way to do that?

UPDATE 
I tried adding a shell script to the automator workflow

```
fn=$(ls -t | head -n1)
mv -f -- "$fn" ./<subdirectory>/
```

But am having trouble with the path in the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -t | head -n1` is good, but be careful; if the subdir is the most recently modified, it would take the first slot, not only resulting in an attempt to move that dir into itself (not allowed, and that may be your problem "with the path in the second line"), but potentially deleting the rest of the files, including the one you want to keep. There are many ways to filter out any directories; off the top of my head you could `ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | head -n1` . Note that adding a file to a directory affects that directories mtime (last modified time) on posix.

Removing all files is easy, once you move out the file you want to keep, just `rm *`. Note that this will not remove directories (so long as you do not put -r), which I think is what you want because it appears you're moving the file you want to keep to a sub-directory of where it was.

You may want to add some error trapping too, so if a step fails later steps don't delete files you don't want deleted. I do not use automator, but this should work so long as your using real bash: (including other schedulers, like cron, as long as you get into the correct working dir first)

```sh
mv -- "$(ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | head -n1)" subdirectory/ && rm *
```

&& means do what follows only if what preceeds succeeds. Adding `./` to the beginning of the destination file does nothing, though keeping the `/` at the end prevents creating a new file named "subdirectory" if it does not already exist. Also, I'm pretty sure the "<>" in the code snippet you sent is to mark it as being different from your actual code, but just in case: Note that the subdirectory, whatever it's called, may need special handling if it does actually contain those characters.

**Edit:**

I just noticed in the question the constraint "get a filtered list of files in a folder that are more than 30 days old". So, a slight change: (use find to compare the time)

```sh
mv -- "$(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -printf '%T@ %f\n' | sort -rn | head -n1 | cut -d\  -f2-)" subdirectory/ && find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

Explanation: find in the current directory (not subdirs, so maxdepth 1) files (not directories, type f) that have a mtime of at least 30 days in the past (-mtime +30) and print the time of the modification and the name (%T@ %f); sort as if it were a number (-n) in reverse order (-r); take only the first (head -n1); extract the filename (second+ space-delimited field) and move it to subdirectory. If successful, delete anything that fits the same find criteria as before.

I would not put the files in a environment variable unless the disk is /very/ slow and uncached. The time spent filtering out the filename you moved probably takes more effort then requerying the disk, unless you have an insane number of files, in which case they might not fit in the environment section.

**Edit 2:** KamilCuk is right. Use null terminated, as null is (the only character) not allowed in filenames:

```sh
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -printf '%T %f\0' | sort -z -t' ' -r -n -s -k1 | head -z -n1 | cut -z -d' ' -f2- | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} subdirectory/ && find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

Comment: [Why not to parse ls and what to do instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, obviously there are some weird potential filenames that might cause issues. Actually testing this (with `-print` instead of `-delete`), I see that find replaces each newlines with a ? *unless* outputting to a non-tty, so yes, the move might break in that case (with failure status, so the delete won't happen). If filenames containing newlines is to be supported, then a more robust filtering program is needed, in which case something should be created in a language that can handle raw character codes better (C).

Comment: Just use zero separated streams. Like `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -printf '%T %f\0' | sort -z -t' ' -r -n -s -k1 | head -z -n1 | cut -z -d' ' -f2- | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} subdirectory/`

Comment: I didn't know sort had that option, but yeah, that's great. I will definitely use that someday.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks heaps. I'd been slogging thru it and kind of got it to work, but this is much better. Much appreciated.